# How does heroku and sidekiq run the jobs outside of my main dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm confused how heroku and sidekiq work.  My Procfile looks like:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e $RAILS_ENV
```

Now inside my rails I run my sidekiq jobs in my code like:

```
SomeWorker.perform_async(some.id)
```

Now will this automatically somehow make this process run in the worker dyno?

If yes, how does it just know to run this out of process?

It is confusing because when I am in my main git folder I can run heroku commands and I know this are for my web dyno, but how do I then see the logs for my worker dyno or will these be in my same dyno logs?

Answer (score 3):

When you setup your `Procfile`, you're telling Heroku to setup 2 types of dynos: `web` and `worker`. It's likely that these are using the same Rails app code but are starting up with different commands (`bundle exec puma` vs. `bundle exec sidekiq`). You then can scale however many VMs (dynos) that you need for each type of process.

The glue that holds the two together is Redis. When you run `SomeWorker.perform_async(some.id)` from your `web` process, you're adding a record to Redis describing a job to run. Your `worker` process watches Redis for new records and then processes them.

The Heroku logs show logs from all running dynos. So you should see logs from both your `web` and `worker` processes mixed in together.

Comment: Right. I guess I didn't know how heroku works either :) Somehow I was totally sure that it'd run sidekiq in the same dyno.

Comment: It takes a while to fully understand it. This book really helped me out. http://www.theherokuhackersguide.com/